# How to model a query/criteria search for a bookstore repository

Tags: java, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have a book repository/bookstore where clients can search for a book based on author, ISBN, name and lots more. This could potentially lead to numerous find methods in the repository as more fields are added in the future. To solve this, I want to have one find method that takes in a `Query` object that will encapsulate the search. I also would like to have a `QueryBuilder` class construct the query. However, I'm having trouble implementing these classes. Any suggestions?? Also as an aside, should pagination support be the concern of the repository or the client constructing the query.

My BookRepository class currently looks like this:

```
public interface Bookstore {
    Iterable<Book> find(Query query);

    Iterable<Book> find(Query query, int start, int len);

    void add(Book book);

    void remove(Query query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html) pattern. It should support a builder.